# connection.execute

Tags: database, vb.net, connection

```
`Dim con1 As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs1 As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim sql1 As String
sql1 = "Update Balance set Balance_Amt = (Balance_Amt + " & a & ") where Company = " & Combo3.Text
con1.Execute (sql1)
```

"Can anyone say why this code does not work? It says No value for one or more required parameters"

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that the immediate problem is that the SQL fragment

```
where Company = value
```

is invalid SQL. It should be quoted:

```
where Company = 'value'
```

But you really should be using SQL parameters.

1. I would have avoided this issue since the parameter would have been automatically quoted as necessary.
2. It would have made the code easier to read.
3. It would not be susceptible to SQL Injection attacks.

e.g.

```
Using cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Balance SET Balance_Amt = (Balance_Amt + @a) WHERE Company=@company", con1)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", a)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company", company)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

Comment: Good answer right to the point, but the example is a bit out of context. ADODB is not ADO.NET

Comment: I had not realized the OP was using ADODB (Of course now that I look at it again, it seems obvious). I just learned enough VB.NET syntax to translate what I would normally write in C# using ADO.NET. Anyone who knows ADODB, feel free to modify (or add to) my example.

Answer (score 0):

Print out the sql statement and see if it is ok, copy/paste it to the sql management studio.
I think you are missing apostrophes around the string Combo3.Text.

Also consider what sql it would result in if Combo3.Text contains

```
'a'; delete from Balance
```